# bootstrap4 input file upload won't show uploaded file name in input ?? how to solve using angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, angular5

In Angular component I've used bootstrap 4 input file tag but after selecting it won't display the selected file name in place of "choose file".

So, how to show selected file name in input tag using angular or css?

[image]

Comment: can you provide fiddle or plunker link

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML file should have below content:

```
    <input type="file" id="ifile" class="form-control" #fileInput (change)="preUpload($event)" />
    <label class="custome-file-label" *ngIf=!isFileChosen>Choose file</label>
    <label class="custome-file-label" *ngIf=isFileChosen>{{fileName}}</label>
```

You can write below method in your component.ts file:

```
isFileChosen:boolean = false;
fileName: string = '';
preUpload(event){
  let file = event.target.files[0];
  if (event.target.files.length > 0){
  this.isFileChosen = true;
  }        
  this.fileName = file.name;
}
```

If you will upload some file, then the count will be greater than 0 and you will able to display your name instead of Choose File label.

Please see a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-krfynr)